# Perl regex: extracting names from a difficult string

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract the three names from the following string:

> author={Kordesch, Karl and Simader, G{\"u}nter and Wiley, John Ray},

This should provide three matches:

1. Kordesch, Karl
2. Simader, G{\"u}nter
3. Wiley, John Ray

I have been wracking my brain to no avail. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the string literally contain a \? Is it really `G{\"u}` or did the encoding of ü get mangled?

Comment: Is every name always separated by `and`?

Comment: @Schwern: It's probably LaTeX code. That's (one way) of producing an ü there.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it literally contains the four character string representing the umlatted u: {\"u}

Comment: @Schwern It looks like TeX (BibTeX specifically) markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm sure you can do this in a single regex somehow, it's simplest to do this in steps.

First, split the key/value by splitting on `=`.

```
my($key,$names) = split /=/, $string;
```

Now that we have the value, we can strip off the `{},`

```
$names =~ s/^{(.*)},?$/$1/;
```

With all that cleaned off you have just `Kordesch, Karl and Simader, G{\"u}nter and Wiley, John Ray` which is easy enough to split into names.

```
my @names = split /\s+and\s+/, $names;
```

---

The trailing `,` makes me suspect that this is part of a larger data structure. In that case it would be safer and more robust to parse the data structure rather than trying to parse it ad hoc line by line. [In the comments it was mentioned this looks like it might be TeX or BibTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337308/perl-regex-extracting-names-from-a-difficult-string/54337438#comment95491995_54337308). There's [any number of modules to parse that](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=+bibtex).

Comment: Hey, ask a perl question, get a perl answer... :) Thank you. I appreciate your helpful input. I would like to see if there is a single regex that will do this but if one is not forthcoming I will accept your answer. Thanks again, man.